# Why do FGC when tenured generation occupy 50% and metaspace occupy 98%

Tags: java, garbage-collection, metaspace

**JVM Version**
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
**JVM Memory usage like:**
Heap
 def new generation   total 33216K, used 4K [0x00000000fa000000, 0x00000000fc400000, 0x00000000fc400000)
  eden space 29568K,   0% used [0x00000000fa000000, 0x00000000fa001080, 0x00000000fbce0000)
  from space 3648K,   0% used [0x00000000fc070000, 0x00000000fc070000, 0x00000000fc400000)
  to   space 3648K,   0% used [0x00000000fbce0000, 0x00000000fbce0000, 0x00000000fc070000)
 tenured generation   total 61440K, used 34490K [0x00000000fc400000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 61440K,  56% used [0x00000000fc400000, 0x00000000fe5aeaa8, 0x00000000fe5aec00, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 51022K, capacity 51693K, committed 57344K, reserved 57344K

**JVM args is:**
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-server" "-XX:+UseSerialGC" "-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=31345" "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=false" "-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures" "-XX:+FlightRecorder
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:-UseCompressedClassPointers
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=56m" "-XX:MarkStackSize=32768" "-XX:MarkStackSizeMax=4194304" "-XX:SharedReadWriteSize=12582912" "-XX:StackShadowPages=3" "-XX:VMThreadStackSize=512
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=48m" "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=48m" "-XX:CompileThreshold=3000" "-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Xms96m" "-Xmx96m" "-XX:NewRatio=2
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss256k -Xmn36m"

**Current gc log is:**
23636.561: [Full GC (Last ditch collection) 23636.561: [Tenured: 34568K->34568K(61440K), 0.1815189 secs] 34568K->34568K(94656K), [Metaspace: 51111K->51111K(57344K)], 0.1816524 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
23636.744: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) 23636.744: [Tenured: 34568K->34609K(61440K), 0.1811110 secs] 34770K->34609K(94656K), [Metaspace: 51111K->51111K(57344K)], 0.1813034 secs] [Times: user=0.18 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
23636.926: [Full GC (Last ditch collection) 23636.926: [Tenured: 34609K->34609K(61440K), 0.1731652 secs] 34609K->34609K(94656K), [Metaspace: 51111K->51111K(57344K)], 0.1734136 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
23637.100: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) 23637.101: [Tenured: 34609K->34567K(61440K), 0.1757107 secs] 34667K->34567K(94656K), [Metaspace: 51111K->51111K(57344K)], 0.1758392 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.17 secs]
23637.276: [Full GC (Last ditch collection) 23637.276: [Tenured: 34567K->34567K(61440K), 0.1675901 secs] 34567K->34567K(94656K), [Metaspace: 51111K->51111K(57344K)], 0.1677021 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.17 secs]
23637.447: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) 23637.447: [Tenured: 34567K->34667K(61440K), 0.1613939 secs] 35383K->34667K(94656K), [Metaspace: 51117K->51117K(57344K)], 0.1615529 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs]
23637.609: [Full GC (Last ditch collection) 23637.609: [Tenured: 34667K->34667K(61440K), 0.1629309 secs] 34667K->34667K(94656K), [Metaspace: 51117K->51117K(57344K)], 0.1631633 secs] [Times: user=0.15 sys=0.00, real=0.17 secs]

**Jstat status check is:**
***1)./jdk1.8.0_111/bin/jstat -gc 3013 1000 5***
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
3648.0 3648.0  0.0    0.0   29568.0    41.8    61440.0    35100.7   57344.0 51127.3  0.0    0.0      391    2.904 105988 17121.850 17124.755
3648.0 3648.0  0.0    0.0   29568.0   562.5    61440.0    35049.7   57344.0 51127.3  0.0    0.0      391    2.904 105994 17122.837 17125.742
3648.0 3648.0  0.0    0.0   29568.0   155.8    61440.0    35539.3   57344.0 51123.7  0.0    0.0      391    2.904 106000 17123.893 17126.797
3648.0 3648.0  0.0    0.0   29568.0    0.0     61440.0    35272.7   57344.0 51123.7  0.0    0.0      391    2.904 106005 17124.776 17127.681
3648.0 3648.0  0.0    0.0   29568.0    0.0     61440.0    35269.9   57344.0 51123.7  0.0    0.0      391    2.904 106011 17125.791 17128.696
***2)./jdk1.8.0_111/bin/jstat -class 3013 1000 5***
Loaded  Bytes  Unloaded  Bytes     Time
 23996 38866.6    15278 22602.0    2294.53
 23996 38866.6    15278 22602.0    2294.53
 23997 38868.1    15279 22603.6    2294.53
 23997 38868.1    15279 22603.6    2294.53
 23997 38868.1    15279 22603.6    2294.53

Answer (score 0):

metaspace occupy is 98%, this is more than MinMetaspaceFreeRatio.